# Counting numbers

Tags: numbers, mathematics, count

I’ve been noticing more questions on [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com) recently that want to “count the number” of something, e.g. count the number of arrangements of a certain type. My initial reaction to this was: “You don’t count the number of arrangements; you count the arrangements.” Then I checked the [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=counts%20the%20number%20of%20ways%2Ccounts%20the%20ways&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccounts%20the%20number%20of%20ways%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccounts%20the%20ways%3B%2Cc0) and found that “counts the number of ways” is actually more common than “counts the ways”. The difference is [even more pronounced](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=count%20the%20times%2Ccount%20the%20number%20of%20times&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccount%20the%20times%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccount%20the%20number%20of%20times%3B%2Cc0) for “count the number of times” vs. “count the times”. Then I checked my own answers on the site and found that I’d written “count the number” so often myself that [the search results](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A6622%20%22count%20the%20number%22) don’t fit on a page, and that I’d in fact written “[count the number of ways](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A6622%20%22count%20the%20number%20of%20ways%22)” more often than “[count the ways](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A6622%20%22count%20the%20ways%22)”.

This humbling experience made me wonder whether perhaps I was being too prescriptivist and whether “counting the number of” might be a perfectly normal English expression. What do you think – does “count the number of ways” sound right to you? Do you perhaps even prefer it over “count the ways”?

(I originally [asked this at meta.math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31379), where it was closed as off-topic and better suited
 to this site.)

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question: your research showed "count the number of" to be the more common expression. Elizabeth Barrett Browning might not agree though.

Comment: Even in Barret's time, *count the number* was tied for first as the most common "count the (wildcard)" ngram. There was a peak in *count the cost* used in Christian religious texts at the time. Otherwise, *count the number* has been the most common ngram for as long as good data exists (since about 1740 or so).